# How do I manage a frequently changing vector in c++?

Tags: c++, vector, openframeworks

I am trying to create a vector that holds a series of paths in c++. I'm having trouble understanding how to add them in a way that allows me to properly remove them later.

I have a contour finder that returns a path for each contour it finds. It keeps finding new contours, but say it finds 3 contours to start with. I want to create and modify 3 extra offset paths for each path returned, so I know that my vector will be 9 elements in size.

How can I add each path and the offsets to the vector, and subsequently remove the path and the offsets when the 'root' path disappears? What if I change the number of offsets on the fly?

One thought I had was to create a multidimensional vector

```
vector< vector<ofPolyline> >
```

This, I'd imagine, would let me delineate each path returned from my contour tracker, and within that I store all of it's associated offset paths. But is this incorrect?

Comment: Write elegant code that expresses the problem succinctly. if it performs too slowly, you can ask here or on codereview for advice. Suggest you have a go with the vector solution and see how it pans out.

Comment: Some sort of tree structure might be better at delete, if you are talking about directory paths. Although if the number of paths is small, then who cares. (or are you talking about graphs?)

Comment: How may paths?  How many offsets per path?  How often is insertion and deletion of each of these happening?

Comment: There might be around 10 paths at any given time, and somewhere between 3 to 10 offsets for each path. (More likely less of each in a usually case). These paths are derived from camera input (silhouettes) so they are fairly dense with points. They are being updated at about 30 times per second, although new contours might show up or disappear every few seconds.

Comment: Do you have a plan on how to uniquely identify a contour? I am assuming a contour is a `vector<ofPolyline>` This would seem like potentially a key element if you care about isolating a specific contour to which you want to add or remove offsets. An index to the container vector (your vector of contours) would not help in the case you support removing specific contours.

Answer (score 0):

Hashtable data structure suits good for you..

The o(1) search/look up is its specialty.
You can easily find its implementation in internet

Here is one example
http://pumpkinprogrammer.com/2014/06/21/c-tutorial-intro-to-hash-tables/

**You can use STL containers like multimap or unordered_multimap (C++11 onwards).**